# How does a "proxy server" work

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I'm trying to implement a simple ProxyServer to analyze traffix between a connected device and the outside world.

- The iPhone (for example) is configured to use a proxy to 192.168.1.10:8080.
- My proxy server (on 192.168.1.10) will be listening on the port 8080.
- The iPhone tries to connect to http://google.com:80, or ftp://somehost.com:21/ it sends a request to the proxy server (port 8080), which is supposed to contact google.com at port 80 and somehost at post 21.

So I figured it would be something like this:

```
    //Accept incoming 
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    //Log incoming requests

    //Send to remote server on behalf of my device
    Socket remote = new Socket(remoteHost, remotePort);
    //forward the same data to remote client..

    //wait for the reply

    //send to my device
```

How to know the remote port/host to forward the request to?

What did I miss?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I think that you will find that building a proxy server is not actually simple. I've done it before on top of [netty.io](https://netty.io)

Comment: Well I'd like first to understand the logic of it. How does the proxy know where to forward? Is there a protocoll on top of everything with the forwarding information?

Comment: When I set the proxy on my iPhone, where does it put the `destination port` information ?

Comment: How you write it depends on what you want it for. If it's just a real proxy it's simplicity itself: just read the request, form the connection, and start copying bytes. But if you want to analyze the traffic it's a different matter. Further information please.

Comment: And send it to what adresse? Actually i want to intercept and read whats going on before forwarding to their acutal destination.